# Elastic search exact field value retrieval

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Now I bumped into other problem - how can I choose only the values of the field which fit fuzzy query? Let's say there are different names in the field university like: education : [MIT, Stanford University, Michingan university] but I want to select only stanford university.
Let's say I can do aggregation on each fuzzy query, which would return ALL counts and all names of universities from field education. What I need - to get aggregations only of exact values which match fuzzy query. Let's say if I do a fuzzy query for Stanford University and a field education holds values of [MIT, Stanfordddd University, Michigan University], I would like a query to bring me back only a value of 'Stanfordddd University', not all three of them. Thanks!

Comment: The tag `fuzzy` that you used, bears the description "Do not use". Please do not use tags that have "Do not use" in their description. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this feature, your field `education` must be of type [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and you make use of [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) feature to retrieve the only concerned value.

Below is the sample mapping as how your field `education` would be in this case:

**Mapping:**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings":{
    "mydocs":{
      "properties":{
        "education": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Documents:**

```
POST my_index/mydocs/1
{
  "education": [
  {
    "value": "Stanford University"
  },
  {
    "value": "Harvard University"
  }]
}

POST my_index/mydocs/2
{
  "education": [
  {
    "value": "Stanford University"
  },
  {
    "value": "Princeton University"
  }]
}
```

**Fuzzy Query on Nested Field:**

```
POST my_index/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "nested":{  
         "path":"name",
         "query":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "span_near":{  
                        "clauses":[  
                           {  
                              "span_multi":{  
                                 "match":{  
                                    "fuzzy":{  
                                       "name.value":{  
                                          "value":"Stanford",
                                          "fuzziness":2
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           {  
                              "span_multi":{  
                                 "match":{  
                                    "fuzzy":{  
                                       "name.value":{  
                                          "value":"University",
                                          "fuzziness":2
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "slop":0,
                        "in_order":false
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "inner_hits":{}
      }
   }
}
```

**Sample Response:**

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.6931472,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "education": [
            {
              "value": "Stanford University"
            },
            {
              "value": "Princeton University"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "name": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 0.6931472,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "my_index",
                  "_type": "mydocs",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "education",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 0.6931472,
                  "_source": {
                    "value": "Stanford University"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "education": [
            {
              "value": "Stanford University"
            },
            {
              "value": "Harvard University"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "name": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 0.6931472,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "my_index",
                  "_type": "mydocs",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "education",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 0.6931472,
                  "_source": {
                    "value": "Stanford University"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice the section `inner_hits` where you'd see that only the relevant/concerned document having `Stanford University` would be returned.

Elasticsearch by default returns *the entire document* as response. To certain extent you can perform filtering based on *fields* using `_source`, however it doesn't allow you to filter values.

Hope this helps!