# Elastic search loop over values of two indices

Tags: loops, elasticsearch, lucene

I am looking for a way to loop over the values of field X coming from INDEX_1 with values of the field Y coming from INDEX_2.

Has anybody faced/done such/similiar task?

Comment: I guess there is someone who knows a way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy within Elastic search itself! Anytime you would specify an index, you can separate additional indices by comma.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index1,index2/_search?q=yourQueryHere'
```

You can also search all indices with _all.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?q=yourQueryHere'
```

Here's some helpful documentation from elasticsearch's website. This site has TONS of info, but it is a bit difficult to find sometimes, IMO.

> http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html
>   http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html

Comment: Hi, thanks Kavi! That really makes sense (even I just found it also on web). I guess I will come back to you soon with some question/-s!