# match an indexed phrase with fuzzy in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the 2 following entries indexed in elasticsearch:

```
united states
united states minor outlying islands
```

I'd like to fuzzy match with a distance of 1, thus if i send the follwing query terms, I'd like to only match `united states`:

```
united tsates
unitedstates
united sates
```

I've tried a `span_near` approach as suggested in other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652765/elastic-search-match-phrase-fuzziness) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652765/elastic-search-match-phrase-fuzziness)), but this still matches both `united states` and `united states minor outlying islands`.

How can I match only `united states` with the aforementioned list of terms ?

First attempt:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match":{
               "country_name":{
                  "query":"united tsates",
                  "fuzziness":1,
                  "operator": "and"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Attempt with `span_near`:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "span_near":{
         "clauses":[
            {
               "span_multi":{
                  "match":{
                     "fuzzy":{
                        "country_name":{
                           "fuzziness":"1",
                           "value":"united"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "span_multi":{
                  "match":{
                     "fuzzy":{
                        "country_name":{
                           "fuzziness":"1",
                           "value":"tsates"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "slop":0,
         "in_order":"true"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a fuzzy query on keyword field? Something like this

```
GET test_index/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
          "country_name.keyword": "united tsates"
        }
      }
    }
```